# Some points about implementing a garbage collector

Tags: garbage-collection

I'm trying to implement a simple programming language.  I want to make the user of it not have to manage the memory, so I decided to implement a garbage collector.  The simplest way I can think of after checking out some material is like this:

There are two kinds of heap zones.  The first is for storing big objects(bigger than 85,000 bytes), the other is for small objects. In the following I use BZ for the first, SZ for the second.

The BZ uses the mark and sweep algorithm, because moving a big object is expensive. I don't compact, so there will be fragmentation.

The SZ uses generations with mark-compact. There are three generations: 0, 1, and 2. Allocation requests go directly to generation 0, and when generation 0 is full, I will do garbage collection on it, the survivals will be promoted to generation 1. generation 1 and generation 2 will also do garbage collection when full.

When the virtual machine starts, it will allocate a big memory from the OS to be used as a heap zone in the virtual machine  The BZ and every generation in SZ will occupy a fixed portion of memory, and when an allocation request can't be satisfied, the virtual machine will give an error OTM (out of memory).  This has a problem: when the virtual machine starts, even getting the program to run on it should need only a little memory, but it still uses a lot.   A better way will be for the virtual machine get a small amount of memory from the OS, and then when the program needs more memory the virtual machine will get more from the OS. I am going to allocate a larger memory for the generation 2 in SZ, and then copy all the things in generation 2 to the new memory zone. And do the same thing for the BZ.

The other problem occurs when the BZ is full and SZ is empty, I would be silly not be able to satisfy a big object allocation request even though we in fact have enough free heap size for the big object in SZ.  How to deal with this problem?

Comment: wondering if you can dynamically resize BZ and SZ based on heuristics (the time you request more memory from O.S) ...

Comment: @Imposter Would you please say more, I can't catch your point

Comment: Well, have you checked what other memory management systems do?

Answer (score 4):

I am trying to understand your methodology . Since you didnt mention your strategy completely, i am having some assumption.

**NOTE** : Following is my hypothetical analysis and may not be practically possible .So please skip answer if you don't have time .

Your are trying to use Generational GC  with  changes ; There are classifications of 2 types

(1) big size objects **BZ** and

(2)small size objects **SZ** .

**SZ** perform generational GC with compaction( CMS )

From above understanding we know that the **SZG2** has long lived objects .I am expecting that GC in **szG2** is not as frequent as **SZG1 or SZG0** since long lived object generally tend to live longer so less dead collection and size of **SZG2** will be  more as time lapses, so GC'ing takes lot of time traversing all elements  ,so doing frequent GC on **SZG2** is less productive(long GC spike  ,so notable delay for user) compared to that of **SZG1 or SZG0** .

And similarly for **BZ** there might be large memory requirement (as big object occupy more space) . So in order to address you query

`"The other problem occurs when the BZ is full and SZ is empty, I would be silly not be able to satisfy a big object allocation request even though we in fact have enough free heap size for the big object in SZ. How to deal with this problem?"`

Since you said that " when the program needs more memory the virtual machine will get more from the OS"

I have a small idea, may not be productive or may not be possible to implement and completely dependent on your implementation of GCHeap structure .
Let your virtual machine allocate memory like follows

[image]

Coming to the possibility (i borrowed idea  from "memory segments of program" as shown below) below is possible at low level .

[image]

As shown in above **figure a** GCHeap structure has to be defined in such a way that **SZG0** and **BZ** expand towards each other .For implementing GCHeap structure mentioned in **figure a**, **figure b** we need to have proper convention of memory growth in zones **SZG[0-2]** size and **BZ**  .

So if you want to divide your heap for application into multiple heaps then you can pile **figure A** over **figure B** to decrease fragmentation (when i say fragmentation `it means "when the BZ is full and SZ is empty, I would be silly not be able to satisfy a big object allocation request even though we in fact have enough free heap size for the big object in SZ."` ).

So effective structure will be

```
            B
            |
            B
            |
            B
            |
            B
            |
            A
```

Now its completely depends on heuristics to decide whether to consider GCHeap data structure in multiple GCHeap structures like GCHeapA , GCHeapB or take it as single heap based on requirement .

If you don't want to have  multiple heaps then you can use figure A with small correction by `Setting base address of **SZG2** to top of heap`

The key reason behind Figure a is as follows :
we know that **SZG0**  get GC'ed frequently so it  can have more free space compared to **SZG1** and **SZG2** ,since dead objects are removed and survived object gets moved to **SZG1** and **SZG2** .So if allocation of **BZ** is more it can grow towards **SZG0** .

In the **figure a** base address of  **SZG1** and **SZG2** are contigious because **SZG2** is more prone to out of memory error as old generation object tend to live longer and GC'ing doesnt sweep much  (**NOTE** :  it is just my assumption and opinion ) so **SZG2** is kept bound outwards .

Comment: "The other problem occurs when the BZ is full and SZ is empty, I would be silly not be able to satisfy a big object allocation request even though we in fact have enough free heap size for the big object in SZ. How to deal with this problem?" 
For this, why don't we use the buddy allocator logic from linux such that the SZ blocks are combined dynamically for BZ allocations and vice versa.